# GridView item looks not as expected - Android

Tags: android, gridview

I try to use a `GridView` object in a specific fragment in my app. 
I created a layout file for the grid item and in the layout editor, the preview image looks good, as expected.

The problem arises when I run the app in my emulator. The whole item layout gets shrinked and the image I put in the middle suddenly jumps to the top of the layout.

Screenshot of the layout editor:
https://i.gyazo.com/8ed96ed19719a578388cc48aba6829f8.png

Screenshot of the emulator:
https://i.gyazo.com/cca0a32b3d102025df5d5369dc7c0efc.png

Here is the xml code for the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/documents_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:columnWidth="@dimen/document_grid_item_width"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/empty_view_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/empty_view_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/recent_empty_view" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/empty_view_arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/empty_view_image"
            android:layout_below="@+id/empty_view_image"
            android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
            android:scaleX="0.75"
            android:scaleY="0.75"
            android:src="@drawable/empty_view_arrow" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the item layout xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/document_grid_item_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/document_grid_item_height"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/draft_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:background="@drawable/document_grid_item_bg"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/draft_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/draft_icon" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/draft_more_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/draft_date_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="20 May 17"
            android:textSize="11sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the adapter code:

```
package com.silverfix.dgdeditor.adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.silverfix.dgdeditor.R;
import com.silverfix.dgdeditor.utils.DocumentPack;
import com.silverfix.dgdeditor.utils.views.ViewClickListener;
import com.silverfix.dgdeditor.utils.views.ViewLongClickListener;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by David on 14/05/2017.
 */

public class DraftsGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Listeners
    private ViewClickListener clickListener;
    private ViewLongClickListener longClickListener;

    private Activity context;
    private List<DocumentPack> dataSet;

    private int clickedItemPos = -1;

    public DraftsGridAdapter(Activity context, List<DocumentPack> dataSet) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataSet = dataSet;
    }

    public void setClickedItemPosition(int clickedItemPos) {
        this.clickedItemPos = clickedItemPos;
    }

    public int getClickedItemPosition() {
        return clickedItemPos;
    }

    public void setClickListener(ViewClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public void setLongClickListener(ViewLongClickListener longClickListener) {
        this.longClickListener = longClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dataSet.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final DocumentPack pack = dataSet.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.draft_grid_item, null);

            DraftViewHolder viewHolder = new DraftViewHolder(context, convertView);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        // Instance of a view holder from the tag of the convertView
        DraftViewHolder viewHolder = (DraftViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        // Set the adapter position to the current view holder
        viewHolder.setAdapterPosition(position);

        // Bind the click listeners to the root view of the view holder
        // viewHolder.bindClick(clickListener);
        // viewHolder.bindLongClick(longClickListener);

        // Bind the data to the view holder
        viewHolder.bindData(pack);

        return convertView;
    }

    private class DraftViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {

        private View.OnClickListener clickListener;
        private View.OnLongClickListener onLongClickListener;

        private View rootView;

        private ImageView moreButton;
        private TextView date;

        private int position;

        public DraftViewHolder(final Activity context, final View rootView) {
            this.rootView = rootView;

            date = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.draft_date_tv);
            moreButton = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.draft_more_button);

            context.registerForContextMenu(rootView);

            rootView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

            moreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    context.openContextMenu(rootView);
                    setClickedItemPosition(position);
                }
            });
        }

        void setAdapterPosition(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }

        void bindClick(final ViewClickListener clickListener) {
            this.clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    clickListener.onClick(position);
                }
            };

            rootView.setOnClickListener(this.clickListener);
        }

        void bindLongClick(final ViewLongClickListener longClickListener) {
            this.onLongClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    longClickListener.onLongClick(position);
                    return false;
                }
            };

            rootView.setOnLongClickListener(this.onLongClickListener);
        }

        void bindData(DocumentPack draft) {
            String formatDate = draft.getFormattedDate();

            date.setText(formatDate);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, You can try...

```
`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dp" >
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
```

`

If this don't work you can also try to use `android:stretchMode="columnWidth"`